# How to set an action in a UIAlertView?

Tags: ios, uialertview

The UIAlertView Delegate is not getting called. The alert is showing but the buttons do not work. I want one button to open google maps and the other button to open native maps app.

```
-(IBAction)showAlertView {
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                      initWithTitle:@"Obrir en..."
                      message:@""
                      delegate:self
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Millor no..."
                      otherButtonTitles:@"Mapes",@"Google Maps",nil];
[alert show];
}
-(void)showAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alert clickedButtonAtIndex (NSInteger)otherButtonTitles
{
NSString *title = [alert buttonTitleAtIndex:otherButtonTitles];

if([title isEqualToString:@"Mapes"])
{
    UIApplication *ourApplication = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    NSString *ourPath = @"http://maps.apple.com/?q=41.11670,1.25812";
    NSURL *ourURL = [NSURL URLWithString:ourPath];
    [ourApplication openURL:ourURL];

}
if([title isEqualToString:@"Google Maps"])
{
    UIApplication *ourApplication = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    NSString *ourPath = @"http://maps.apple.com/?q=41.11670,1.25812";
    NSURL *ourURL = [NSURL URLWithString:ourPath];
    [ourApplication openURL:ourURL];
}
}
@end
```

Comment: Show us the implementation of your `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` or `alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch :

```
 -(void)showAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alert clickedButtonAtIndex (NSInteger)otherButtonTitles
```

to

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

Comment: If it did remember the check.

Comment: much "safer" to use the `–alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` delegate method instead for alert views.

Comment: @user2367043 Why did you uncheck my answer?